# XML download NSUTF8StringEncoding issue

Tags: objective-c, utf-8, character-encoding

I've make this method for download a XML from a URL.
The issue is the encoding characters.

```
-(void) scaricamentoXML{
    /*Save XML IN LOCALE*/
    NSString* docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSLog(@"Doc dir:  %@:",docsDir);
    //dichiaro il file locale in cui salvare i dati XML
    NSString* fileToDownload = @"provaXML.xml";

    NSString *hostURLString = @"http://demo.gigamips.com/rss.php?authkey=12345";
    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:hostURLString];
    NSLog(@"xmlURL = %@", xmlURL);
    //gestione codifica UTF-8
    NSError *error;
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
    NSLog(@"DataString = %@", dataString);
    //NSData *xml = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
    NSData *xml = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    //creo una stringa di appoggio in encoding UTF8 - verificare se funziona
    NSString *str =  [[NSString alloc] initWithData:xml encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"NSData xml = %@", xml);
    //NSString *newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:xml encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"newStr  = %@", newStr);
    NSString *filePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: fileToDownload];

    //[xml writeToFile: filePath atomically: NO];
    [str writeToFile: filePath atomically: NO];
    /*Save XML IN LOCALE*/


    /*SALVO LE IMMAGINI MINI IN LOCALE*/
    AuthParserImages *parser=[[AuthParserImages alloc]init];
    entryArray=[parser startParserLocale:@"provaXML"];
    GestioneImages *gi = [[GestioneImages alloc]init];
    for(int i =0; i< [entryArray count];i++){
        item=[entryArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [gi saveImageLocal:item.urlImageLow :item.id];
    }
    /*SALVO LE IMMAGINI MINI IN LOCALE*/


    /*CREA IL FILE GESTIONE NEW*/
    gp = [[GestionePlist alloc]init];
    [gp savePlist:@"begin"]; 
    /*CREA IL FILE GESTIONE NEW*/

    [self controlloXML];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

}
```

I can't see the special caracter like ' or accent ù - à - ò etc....

this is the web service http://demo.gigamips.com/rss.php?authkey=12345

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your web service. You are not receiving data encoded with UTF8 string encoding.

Comment: Are there website for checking if this URL is a XML UTF-8 in realtime?

Answer (score 0):

While the XML in http://demo.gigamips.com/rss.php?authkey=12345 *is* encoded in UTF-8, it does not use the right characters. For example, where the curly single quote ’ (U+2019) is supposed to appear it uses U+0092, which is a non-printable control character.

It looks like the author of the document wrote it in [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) and then converted it to UTF-8 using a tool that assumed it was [latin-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1).

You can either try to convince the author to use the proper characters in the first place, or write code to replace the control characters with their probable substitutes (that is, U+2018 instead of U+0091, U+2019 instead of U+0092, U+201C instead of U+0093, and so on.. you can use the character table for Windows-1252 as a reference)